# Can I put a conditional check on a string to see if it ends in "00" inside a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to populate an Objective and ObjectiveDetail objects. Here are the classes I have:

```
partial class Objective
{
    public Objective() {
        this.ObjectiveDetails = new List<ObjectiveDetail>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }
}
public partial class ObjectiveDetail
{
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Objective Objective { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently populating the only the Objective object from this call:

```
 var objectiveData = GetContent.GetType5();
 var objectives = objectiveData.Select(o => new Objective {
                  Name = o.Name,
                  Text = o.Text}
 );
```

The data looks like this:

```
 Name   Text 
 0600   header 1 
 0601   detail abc 
 0602   detail def 
 0603   detail ghi 
 0700   header 2 
 0701 detail xyz
```

Is there a way I could modify my LINQ so that only the data where the `name` field contents end in "00" goes into the Objective object (as it does now) and when the data where the `name` field contents end in "01" then it creates a new ObjectiveDetail object with "detail abc" etc going into the `text` field.

This is a picture of what the end result should look like:

```
A collection of Objectives
     new Objective { name = "header 1",
                        ObjectiveDetails = A collection of ObjectiveDetails 
                                  name = "detail abc" 
                                  name = "detail def" etc.
```

Comment: What about names that end in `02` and `03`?

Comment: what is the type of `objectiveData`?

Comment: Anything ending not in "00" needs to create a new ObjectiveDetail object so I guess it would be like a for loop inside a for loop. The outer loop would create objective records each time there's a "00" then the inside loop would add ObjectiveDetails records when it's not ending in "00".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear what you are asking, but you can put complex logic inside the `Select()` if you need to:

```
var objectives = objectiveData.Select(o =>
{
    var result = new Objective
    {
        Name = o.Name,
        Text = o.Text
    };

    if (o.Name != null && o.Name.EndsWith("01"))
    {
        result.ObjectiveDetails.Add
        (
            new ObjectiveDetail
            {
                ObjectiveDetailId = o.ObjectiveId,
                Name = o.Name,
                Text = o.Text,
                Objective = result
            }
        );
    }

    return result;
});
```

(Note that I'm guessing at what you need; you will need to correct the logic to do what you really want.)

Comment: I think this is more like I need. I didn't realize I could put logic inside like this. I will be using Entity Framework so I think on the inside ObjectiveDetail I won't need to have ObjectiveDetailId and Objective set.

Comment: @Melina the only constraint is the wrapped method has to return some value and has 1 argument, before returning, we can add more code, you can also define the wrapped method separately and pass the name instead of all the code into `Select(...)`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson wouldn't this create a `result` object (of type `Objective`) for the ones that don't end in `00`?

Comment: @SameerSingh Yes it would; I wasn't clear on what the OP needed so I just wanted to show a general approach that they could tailor to their specific requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can do that, using [string.EndsWith] method like:[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx)

```
.Where(r=> r.Name.EndsWith("00"))
```

Modify your query as:

```
 var objectives = objectiveData
                    .Where(r => r.Name.EndsWith("00"))
                    .Select(o => new Objective {
                                               Name = o.Name,
                                               Text = o.Text}
 );
```

Comment: r.Name.EndsWith, surely?

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I was not so clear. Inside of the select can I make it sometimes create a new ObjectiveDetail object if the Name ends in 00?

Comment: @Melina Could you rephrase that? Dunno what you mean.

Comment: @Melina, you need to add the `Where` clause to your query, just updated the answer with the updated query

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to phrase it but now sure how. I have two objects Objective and ObjectiveDetail. Before everything was going into Objective but now I need the details to go into ObjectiveDetail objects. The details are those records where the Name is not ending in "00"

Comment: @Meline that sounds like two queries, an exclusive and inclusive one?

Comment: @Habib - This looks good but if it ends in "00" I need it to create a normal Objective. If it does not end in "01" I need it to create a ObjectiveDetail. Sorry it's not so easy to explain.

Comment: @Melina, for the sake of simplicity you can do that in two queries, I guess you can modify your Select statement to check for name ending with `00` using `?` conditional operator ad then create a different object, but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do some sort of conditional mapping. I like [Matthew Watson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18055244/501556), but it's a bit unclear why he's always creating an `Objective` instance every time. Here's some LINQ-less code which I believe is more readable, and maps the way I think you'd want:

```cs
public class Mapper
{
  public List<Objective> Objectives = new List<Objective>();

  public class Objective
  {
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }

    public Objective()
    {
        ObjectiveDetails = new List<ObjectiveDetail>();
    }
  }
  public class ObjectiveDetail
  {
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Objective Objective { get; set; }
  }

  public void Assign()
  {
    var objectiveData = new[] // Hard-coded test data. We don't know what the type of each item in this list is, so I use an anonymous type
    {
      new {Name = "0600", Text = "Header 06"},
      new {Name = "0601", Text = "06 Detail 01"},
      new {Name = "0602", Text = "06 Detail 02"},
      new {Name = "0603", Text = "06 Detail 03"},
      new {Name = "0700", Text = "Header 07"},
      new {Name = "0701", Text = "07 Detail 01"},
      new {Name = "0702", Text = "07 Detail 02"}
    };

    // Create Objectives first
    var id = 1;
    foreach (var item in objectiveData.Where(i => i.Name.EndsWith("00")))
    {
      Objectives.Add(new Objective { ObjectiveId = id, Name = item.Name, Text = item.Text });
      id++;
    }

    // Create ObjectiveDetails
    id = 1;
    foreach (var item in objectiveData.Where(i => !i.Name.EndsWith("00")))
    {
      var itemLocal = item;
      var matchingObjective = Objectives.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name.StartsWith(itemLocal.Name.Substring(0, 2)));
      var objectiveDetail = new ObjectiveDetail
      {
          ObjectiveDetailId = id,
          Text = item.Text,
          ObjectiveId = matchingObjective != null ? matchingObjective.ObjectiveId : 0,
          Objective = matchingObjective
      };

      if (matchingObjective != null)
      {
          matchingObjective.ObjectiveDetails.Add(objectiveDetail);
      }

      id++;
    }
    // At the end of this method you should have a list of Objectives, each with their ObjectiveDetails children
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps.